# C# - Hilos, Timers y algo mas

Tags: c#, revisión-de-código

Estuve tratando de practicar haciendo un juego en consola antes de pasar a unity, o de mejor dicho de arrancar con unity. Particularmente tuve problemas haciendo los enemigos, llegue a la conclusión que lo que controla a los enemigos es el tiempo y las condiciones que estos tengan. Debido a esto intente crear un timer que no funcionaba asi que en las lineas donde lean timespan salteanlas que fue algo fallido.

La otra forma que se me ocurrió, debido a que time span no funcionaba fue usar `Thread.Sleep()` , que es una pausa de X cantidad de tiempo. El problema que esto presentó fue lo siguiente, al presionar una tecla el enemigo que desciende a golpearnos se ve acelerado por el presionar de los movientos del jugador, debido a que las condiciones de if se cumplen rápido entra mas rápido en sleep.

Mis preguntas son 2:

- ¿Se podía hacer esto en un solo hilo?
- ¿Cómo se instancian los timers correctamente?

  ```
  namespace juego_consola
  {
      class Program
      {
          static void Main(string[] args)
          {

          TimeSpan stop;
          TimeSpan start = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks);
          while (true)
          {

              stop = new TimeSpan(DateTime.Now.Ticks);

              interfaz.marco();
              jugador.imprimo("/A\\", nave.navex+nave.mov, nave.navey);




              Thread hilo = new Thread(new ThreadStart(roca.atake));
              hilo.Start();





              ConsoleKeyInfo tecla = Console.ReadKey();

              if (tecla.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
              {

                  nave.mov += -1;
                  if (nave.navex + nave.mov <= 2)
                  {
                      nave.mov = 0;
                      nave.navex = 2;



                      jugador.imprimo("/A\\", nave.navex, nave.navey);
                      continue;
                  }


                  jugador.imprimo("/A\\", nave.navex + nave.mov, nave.navey);

              }
              if (tecla.Key == ConsoleKey.RightArrow)
              {

                  nave.mov += 1;
                  if (nave.navex + nave.mov >= 56)
                  {
                      nave.mov = 0;
                      nave.navex = 55;


                      jugador.imprimo("/A\\", nave.navex, nave.navey);
                      continue;
                  }


                  jugador.imprimo("/A\\", nave.navex + nave.mov, nave.navey);

              }


          }


      }






  }

  //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
  class nave
  {
      public static int navex = 16;
      public static int navey = 21;
      public static int mov = 0;

  }
  class roca
  {
      public static int rokx = 15;
      public static int roky = 0;
      public static void atake()
      {
          //var t = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
          //t.Elapsed += (sender, args) => roca.atake();
          //t.Start();
          while (roky<=21)
          {


              roca.roky += 1;
          jugador.imprimo("O", roca.rokx, roca.roky);
              Thread.Sleep(1000);
              interfaz.marco();

      }
      }
  }






  //%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
      class jugador
      {
          public static void imprimo(string s, int x, int y)
          {
              Console.SetCursorPosition(x, y);
              Console.WriteLine(s);
          }


  }



  class interfaz
  {
      public static void marco()
      {



          jugador.imprimo("████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████", 0, 0);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 1);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 2);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 3);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 4);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 5);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 6);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 7);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 8);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 9);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 10);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 11);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 12);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 13);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 14);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 15);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 16);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 17);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 18);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 19);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 20);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 21);
          jugador.imprimo("██                                                        ██", 0, 22);
          jugador.imprimo("████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████", 0, 23);
          jugador.imprimo("/A\\", nave.navex + nave.mov, nave.navey);





      }
  }
  ```

  }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estas un poco confundido en el uso de los timers e hilos.

En primer lugar un timer crea un hilo en donde cada cierto tiempo ejecuta el código que le indicas. No necesitas crear un `Thread` manualmente.

Segundo el código que tienes comentado dentro de atake es el que inicia realmente el timer, pero necesitas sacarlo y ponerlo dentro de la función `Main()` fuera del `while` . La inicialización de este permitirá que se llame al método `atake` cada 1000 milisegundos.

Tercero. `atake()` ahora recibe como parámetro el `timer` ya que cuando se cumpla cierta condición (en este caso me parece que cuando llega al borde del marco) se debe detener el timer. Esto ya se controla solo con un `if` ya no con `while`

El código queda mas o menos así

```
static void Main()
{
    var timer = new Timer(1000);
    timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => roca.atake(timer);
    timer.Start();

    while (true)
    {
        interfaz.marco();
        jugador.imprimo("/A\\", nave.navex + nave.mov, nave.navey);
        ConsoleKeyInfo tecla = Console.ReadKey();

        if (tecla.Key == ConsoleKey.LeftArrow)
        // ...
    }
}

class roca
{
    public static int rokx = 15;
    public static int roky = 0;

    public static void atake(Timer timer)
    {
        roca.roky += 1;

        interfaz.marco();
        jugador.imprimo("O", roca.rokx, roca.roky);

        if (roky > 21)
        {
            timer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para crear un objeto Timer tienes que hacer lo siguiente:

```
Timer tActualizar = new Timer(Tick, "", 3600000, 3600000);
```

El primer parámetro es la función de callback a la que vamos a llamar. El segundo parámetro es un objeto que le pasamos a la función de callback (en mi caso le paso u nstring vacío). El tercer parámetro es el tiempo que espera para la primera ejecución (en milisegundos). El cuarto parámetro es el intervalo de tiempo que va a pasar entre llamada y llamada a la función de callback (en milisegundos).

Lo que te faltará es definir la función de callback, se declara así:

```
static void Tick(object data)
    {...}
```

En el método Tick es donde controlarías el movimiento de los enemigos si no me equivoco y en el hilo principal es donde controlas la interacción con el usuario. Creo que Timer internamente crea un hilo a parte del principal.

Yo diría que con un sólo hilo no lo puedes hacer, necesitas un Timer o al menos 2 hilos, uno para controlar el movimiento de los enemigos y otro para el del usuario.

Espero haber ayudado.