# C#- Entendiendo eventos , eventhandlers y delegados

Tags: c#

Tengo saber si tengo claro 4 puntos que voy a explicar:

1- Un delegado es un tipo de dato que se crea con el fin de almacenar direcciones de metodos(para posteriormente ser llamados) con una firma especifica. ¿Esto es correcto?

2-Un evento se declara en un delegado para lograr llamar a un metodo cuando sea necesario, en ciertos casos se puede utilizar una expresion lambda => para indicar un bloque a ejecutar o un metodo ¿Esto es correcto?

3- El codigo a continuacion se puede ver como creo un delegado, que segun yo esta bien creado y apuntando correctamente a un metodo, entonces en la linea conde estan los %%%%%% quiero saber como ejecutar el metodo del delegado y cuando este se ejecute se dispare el evento en cuestion, mediante la expresion lambda, teniendo como resultado el output "mensaje", "hola"

4-¿Que diferencias hay entre un event y un eventhandler que relacion tienen entre si?

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {


        delegado.direccion_msj = delegado.msj;
        delegado.direccion_msj();
        delegado.direccion_msj += () => eventos.hola_delegado;%%%%%%%%



        Console.ReadKey();

    }

}

class delegado
{
    public delegate void dir_msj();

    public static dir_msj direccion_msj;



    public static void msj()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("mensaje");
        Thread.Sleep(3000);

        Console.WriteLine();


    }

}
class eventos
{


    public static void hola()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Hola");
    }
    public delegate void eventhanhola();
    public static event eventhanhola hola_delegado = hola;
}
```

}

Comment: Hola Shiki, discúlpame, apenas he podido ver tu pregunta. Aquí el tema es que cuando las preguntas tienen muchas preguntas, se cierran por estar demasiado amplias. Recuerda que son preguntas y respuestas a problemas específicos. Aquí lo que te recomendaría es hacer preguntas por separado y a su vez poner un ejemplo, para que con eso ya no te cierren la pregunta :D

Answer (score 4):

> 1- Un delegado es un tipo de dato que se crea con el fin de almacenar
>   direcciones de metodos(para posteriormente ser llamados) con una firma
>   especifica. ¿Esto es correcto?

Sí. Mira como en el siguiente ejemplo se ejecutan ambos metodos que se agregan a la lista de invocacion del delegado `Mensaje` gracias al operador `+=`:

```
    public delegate void Mensaje();

    class Program
    {

        public static void MensajeIngles()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
        }

        public static void MensajeEspanol()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hola mundo");
        }


        public static void Main()
        {
            Mensaje m = MensajeEspanol;
            m += MensajeIngles;

            m();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

[**.Net Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0Ls2vG)

> 2-Un evento se declara en un delegado para lograr llamar a un metodo
>   cuando sea necesario, en ciertos casos se puede utilizar una expresion
>   lambda => para indicar un bloque a ejecutar o un metodo ¿Esto es
>   correcto?

Sí. Se pueden agregar a la lista de invocacion metodos animos(lambdas) que cumplan con la misma asignatura que el delegado:

```
    public delegate void Mensaje();

    class Program
    {
       //..
        public static void Main()
        {
            Mensaje m = MensajeEspanol;
            m += MensajeIngles;
            m += () => 555; // invalido, la signatura de la lambda es Func<int>
            m += () => Console.WriteLine("lenguaje desconocido"); // valido, la lambda iguala la asignatura del delegado
            m();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

> 3- El codigo a continuacion se puede ver como creo un delegado, que
>   segun yo esta bien creado y apuntando correctamente a un metodo,
>   entonces en la linea conde estan los %%%%%% quiero saber como ejecutar
>   el metodo del delegado y cuando este se ejecute se dispare el evento
>   en cuestion, mediante la expresion lambda, teniendo como resultado el
>   output "mensaje", "hola"

La asignatura del delegado y la labda son diferentes. Cuando haces  `() => eventos.hola_delegado;` en realidad estas asignado un metodo que no recibe parametro y que retorne otro metodo con tipo de retorno `void`.

En otras palabras, esto:

```
 () => eventos.hola_delegado;
```

Es igual a:

```
Func<Action> metodoAnomino();
```

Pero la signatura que el delegado espera es `void metodo();`.

**Actualizacion:**

Si quieres imprimir "Hola" y "mensaje" tienes que agregar el metodo `eventos.hola()` a la lista de invocacion

```
   delegado.direccion_msj = delegado.msj;
   delegado.direccion_msj += eventos.hola;
   delegado.direccion_msj();
```

No es valido poder agregar un evento a lista de invocacion de un delegado:

```
m += eventos.hola_delegado; // ERROR, no se puede asignar un evento a un delegado
```

¿Porque no puedes agregar un evento a lista de invocacion de un delegado? Esto nos lleva a la siguiente pregunta:

> 4-¿Que diferencias hay entre un event y un eventhandler que relacion
>   tienen entre si?

Un [`EventHandler`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(v=vs.110).aspx) **es un delegado** que no pasa datos del evento que lo invoco. Mientras que `event` es una clave reservada que crea una capa de abstraccion para los delegados, protegiendolos de modificacion externa. Por ejemplo en el delegado que creamos, si hicieramos esto:

```
    Mensaje m = MensajeEspanol;
    m += MensajeIngles;
    m += () => { Console.WriteLine("lenguaje desconocido"); };
    m = () => { Console.WriteLine("lenguaje desconocido 2"); };
```

Estaríamos sobre escribiendo toda la lista de invocacion y solo nos ejecutaria un solo método que seria el ultimo. Mientras que en un `event` este operador no esta disponible por lo que solo puedes suscribirte/desuscribirte de la lista de invocacion lo que lo hace mas seguro.

Comment: no se por que te dieron -1 tampoco... en cualquier caso te iba a preguntar en el punto 3 como puedo ejecutar el metodo delegado.direccion_msj y cuando este se ejecute dispare el metodo del evento  eventos.hola_delegado; para obtener el ouput "mensaje" "hola"

Comment: Actualize mi respuesta. Dale una mirada.

Comment: claro eso habia pensado al principio pero hace unos dias estaba practicando con esto mira https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/91693/c-hilos-timers-y-algo-mas/91715#91715    entonces me dieron una respuesta en donde se crea un evento que realiza X cosa, cada vez que esta X cosa se realiza al mismo tiempo dispara un metodo llamesmoslo Z. Dicho esto por eso intento crear un evento que imprima "hola " dispare "mensaje " mediante una expresion lambda; pero no quiero almacenar los 2 metodos en el delegado y luego llamarlos por que eso ya lo se hacer, quiero hacer lo que esta en el link y noentie

Comment: Que exactamente es lo que quieres hacer? Puedes mostralo con un ejemplo?

Comment: Claro mira esto esta  en link anterior que te pase var timer = new Timer(1000);
    timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) => roca.atake(timer);
    timer.Start(); El evento timer.Elapsed se ejecuta con un parametro de 1000 que seria un segundo, entonces cada que timer.Elapsed cumple eso dispara un metodo roca atake. Yo en este caso quiero hacer algo parecido creo un evento que imprime"Hola" pero cada vez que este evento llame al metodo que imprime "hola" luego dispare un metodo que esta en un delegado en este caso "mensaje".