# Eventos C# (diferencia con respecto a un Delegado)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, eventos

Estoy estudiando C# pero llegué al tema de Delegados y Eventos, ya se que es un delegado y como funciona:

El delegado es como un "encapsulador" de funciones, donde podemos referenciar un metodo por medio de una instancia del delegado.

Busqué en la pagina de MS, en varios tutoriales y también en esta pregunta
[¿Qué son los Delegados en C#?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1650/qu%C3%A9-son-los-delegados-en-c)

Un ejemplo para uso de delegado lo tengo así:
(ignoren el nombre del namespace)

```
using System;



namespace AdicionEliminacionReferenciasDelegadas

{

delegate void prueba();//contrato, debe tener la misma firma que las funciones que va a recibir

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {




    prueba Test = new prueba(metods.metod1);
        Test += metods.metod2;//apilacion de referencias en la instancia Test, 

        Test();//llamado secuencial de la apilacion (ejecuta las funciones referencias dentro deTest)
        Console.WriteLine("--------------------------------------------------------------------\n Llamado entre clases: \n");

        ejemplo obj = new ejemplo();
        obj.addDelegateStack(metods.metod1);//se añade un metodo de otra clase(estaba probando entre clases)
        obj.addDelegateStack(metods.metod2);
        obj.ejecutarDeleg(); //ejecuta al atributo Test (miembro de clase) donde están contenidas las referencias, de los 2 metodos agregados arriba

        Console.WriteLine("\nEliminacion de metodo 1, el cual se busca y se elimina del ArrayList interno del contenedor delegate .... \n");
        obj.deleteDelegateStack(metods.metod1);

        obj.ejecutarDeleg();//vuelve a ejecutar ese miembro, para comprobar que se elimina una referencia especifica




        Console.ReadLine();
    }


}


class ejemplo
{
    public prueba Test;




    public void addDelegateStack(prueba newDeleg)
    {
        Test += newDeleg;
    }

    public void deleteDelegateStack(prueba newDEleg)
    {
        Test -= newDEleg;
    }

    public void ejecutarDeleg()
    {
        Test();
    }



}



static class metods
{
    public static void metod1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Metodo 1, Estás en clase metods");
    }

    public static void metod2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Metodo 2, sigues en clase metods");
    }
}



}
```

Con este ejemplo logré entender el funcionamiento y aplicarlo a uso entre clases

Ahora sí, mi pregunta es:

Para que sirve el **event** ?

Según Microsoft y  lógica de cualquier humano, un evento es un mensaje enviado para notificar que algo ocurrió.
Pero si ya tengo el **delegate**, con el cual puedo "mandar" funciones entre objetos, por medio de una instancia del delegado, así se podría notificar cualquier cosa *de* y *desde* cualquier clase no?

Entonces como es el uso de **event** ?

*Por cierto, ya sé que hay un par de preguntas sobre este tema, [C#- Entendiendo eventos , eventhandlers y delegados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/92758/c-entendiendo-eventos-eventhandlers-y-delegados) , pero no logro entenderlas, por esa razón, abro otra pregunta...

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Dónde está la referencia de "event" en tu pregunta?

Comment: Te refieres a la utilización de "event" en mi ejemplo?

Comment: Sí, por ningún lado veo tu código y tampoco algún enlace de referencia aparte de los 2 mostrados.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El event es una encapsulación de un delegado.

Cuando accedes a un evento a través de una intancia de tu clase, este solo te permite subcribirte o desubscribirte del evento.

Para que sirve el event ?
    Para enviar notificaciones a los que estén subscritos a dicho evento.

Entonces como es el uso de event ?

```
public delegate void MiDelegado(string input);

public class MiClase
{
    public MiDelegado MiDelegado { get; set; }

    public event MiDelegado MiDelegadoEvent;

    public void InvokeEvent(string input)
    {
        MiDelegado.Invoke(input);

        MiDelegadoEvent(input);
    }
}

internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var instance = new MiClase();

        // Éstas son las dos únicas operaciones permitidas desde la instancia
        // Eliminar la subcripción al evento
        instance.MiDelegadoEvent -= Instance_MiDelegadoEvent;
        // Subscribirse al evento
        instance.MiDelegadoEvent += Instance_MiDelegadoEvent;

        // Ésta llamada la puedes hacer en cualquier método de tu clase o donde estes usando la intancia.
        instance.InvokeEvent("Invocando el evento");

        // De esta forma tienes acceso total a todas las funcionalidades del delegado 
        // Haciendo esto rompes el Pilar de Encapsilación.
        instance.MiDelegado.Invoke("cadena");
        instance.MiDelegado.DynamicInvoke();

    }

    private static void Instance_MiDelegadoEvent(string input)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(input);
    }
}
```